# Why does set key not do anything in AES/SymmetricAlgorithm?

Tags: .net, properties, aes

This MESSED ME UP hard. I thought i was setting the key but i was not. No exceptions, nothing happen except bad results. Why is there a setter if everything is ignored and no exceptions are thrown when i attempt to write? What is the point of the setter on the Keys property?

When i do the below Key value are not changed. After an hour when i realize what was happening i wrote the loop to verify. I also tried aes.Key[0] = val; var b = val == aes.Key[0]; (and messed with it in immediate mode).

Why does it have this behavior?

```
Array.Copy(myKey, aes.Key, aes.Key.Length);

int i = 0;
foreach (var v in aes.Key)
{
    var b = myKey[i++] == v;
    if (!b)
        b = b;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for one thing, you're not using the setter. What you're doing is using the getter (which grabs a *copy* of the key), and setting individual bytes in the copy of the key array returned from the getter (which will not affect the internal state of the `AesCryptoServiceProvider`).

If you want the setter to work correctly, create a new `byte` array and set the property:

```
byte[] newKey = new byte[aes.KeySize / 8];
// generate your key...
aes.Key = newKey;
```

#### Response to comment:

Your example is entirely in managed code and you're returning a direct reference to the byte array `DummyArray` explicitly, so naturally you can set any index you choose because you've elected to return the reference. However, there is no requirement that says you must return a reference to the byte array (this is an implementation detail).

The managed CSPs are simply wrapping calls to the unmanaged [CAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_API), so when the data is marshalled, all you're getting is a copy of the actual data.

Comment: I am getting a COPY!?! Why? With this code below DummyArray is properly set like expected. func() { ...
                d.Key[4]=5;
                DummyArray[4] = 5; }          Byte[] DummyArray_ = new Byte[10];
        Byte[] DummyArray { get { return DummyArray_; } set { DummyArray = value; } }